# Почему происходит расхождение времени в результате и как отловить дубликаты?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет.
Есть примерно вот такая таблица:
(на самом деле она больше - там 5 миллионов строк)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]


Когда я прописываю такую команду:

```
SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE YEAR_MONTH_DAY = '2003-05-05' AND HOUR_MIN_SEC = '03:00:00';
```

То получаю во первых 2 идентичных результата.
(Хотя по идее должен быть один.)

Во вторых в результате дата(или скорее даже какое то время внутри нее)
почему то становится на 1 день раньше чем это прописано в таблице.
(и в запросе тоже)

На счет дубликатов в выдаче - пробовал прописывать Primary Key при создании таблицы(в графе даты и времени. Хотел отловить где этот дубликат зарыт и есть ли он вообще.) - но консоль ругается и пишет, что там какие то дубликаты ее не устраивают.

Какие есть варианты по поиску(идентификации строки) дубликата в таблице в данном случае?
(и главное как это делать правильнее всего с точки зрения подходов, проектирования и т.п.
Сам новичок в программировании.)

На счет даты и времени - пробовал настраивать тайм зоны GTM и UTC - это не поменяло положения вещей.
Почему это может происходить?

P.S. Буду благодарен за советы..

Comment: Избавляетесь от дубликатов, накладываете на нужные столбцы свойство UNIQUE (уникальный). С датами всё просто, у вас где-то проблемы с часовыми поясами.

Comment: Сейчас кажется понимаю что на счет часовых поясов дело вообще не в базе данных а в ноде.

Comment: Вот что я не могу понять:
А каким образом дата будет уникальной - ведь строк же много с одним и тем же днем месяцом и годом?

Comment: Так вы сами нас тут уверяли что 2 идентичных результата быть не может. Уникальный ключ можно делать не только по одному столбцу, но и на несколько сразу

Comment: Я имел ввиду что не может быть одной и той же даты и времени вместе взятые.
Но дата то может быть одинаковой или время (каждый день.) сами по себе.
Если можно делать на несколько сразу - тогда это меняет дело.
Но!
Если там все таки завалялся в талице дубликат - тогда получается и там примари кей создать нельзя будет.
И вот вопрос мой как в таком случае искать дубликат(правильнее всего) - без Primary Key?

Comment: GROUP BY и отсекаете по COUNT(*). И совсем непонятно зачем вы храните время отдельно от даты. Причем дату храните как дата_время

Comment: http://joxi.ru/v29RaqPt3XbbRA
у меня просто котировки в вот таком формате текстовом изначально.
Ну и я просто перекинул это дело в базу точно так же..